# nested transactionTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc, spring-transactions

I have 2 methods that do the following:

```
void withdraw(int amount) {
    transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback() {
        @Override
        public Object doInTransaction() { ... }
    }
}

void deposit(int amount) {
    transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback() {
        @Override
        public Object doInTransaction() { ... }
    }
}
```

Now I want to define a third method that does both in the same transaction:

```
void transferTo(Account other, int amount) {
    transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback() {
        @Override
        public Object doInTransaction() {
            withdraw(amount);
            other.deposit(amount);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Transaction propagation is set to REQUIRED (default).

The use case is obvious, I want withdraw() and deposit() to run in their own transactions if called independently.  However if I call transfer(), I want all statements to run within the same transaction.

However when I run transfer(), I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@e4b2ed] for key [org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource@26cc37d2] bound to thread [http-bio-8084-exec-13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:189)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:234)
```

Answer (score 3):

Well I found the problem... not really a solution to my problem but an explanation as to why I'm getting the error.

The transaction manager I am using is  **org.springframework.ldap.transaction.compensating.manager.ContextSourceAndDataSourceTransactionManager** because I need to perform some LDAP related operations as well.

The only problem is that **ContextSourceAndDataSourceTransactionManager** does not support nested transactions.

Hence nested transactionTemplate calls will fail... inconvenient.

Edit:
Further investigation shows that **ContextSourceTransactionManager** also does not support nested transactions.

Comment: Which Transaction Managers do support nested TransactionTemplates?